# password_needs_rehash alway false after i update my user hash password and login again

Tags: php

i have insert user with password hash to db and login

- 1st time it work password is match ( Ex : $2y$10$QmpJV... )
- and password has been rehash ( $2y$10$JbcQm... )
- after redirect user to Backend Page
- Logout and login again

but 2nd time login Password_needs_rehash false or i'm using it in the wrong way ?

> i want my user password up to date after login

```
if (password_verify($pass, $hashedPassword)) {
                    if (password_needs_rehash($hashedPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
                        $time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                        $newHashedPassword = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        $query="UPDATE tbl_user SET pwd=?,last_login=? where id=?";
                        $stmt=$con->prepare($query);
                        $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$newHashedPassword,$time,$id);
                        if($stmt->execute()){
                            $arr=array(
                                'valid' => true,
                                'error' => 'SQL Execute'
                            );

                        }else{
                            $arr=array(
                                'valid' => false,
                                'error' => 'SQL not Execute'
                            );

                        }
                        return $arr;
                    }else{

                            $arr=array(
                                'valid' => false,
                                'error' => 'Password rehash False'
                            );
                            return $arr;

                    }   
                }else{
                    $arr=array(
                        'valid' => false,
                        'error' => 'Password not Verify'
                    );
                    return $arr;
                }
```

Comment: Why would it need a rehash? Are you misunderstanding what `password_needs_rehash` is for?

Comment: does password_needs_rehash use for make password strong and up to date ?